# recursive sum using prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a question about how can I Sum recursively using prolog, I been trying to do it, but it not count the first element I mean for example if a select the distance between cdmx and nuevoleon it only sums 6 and 7 but 3 and 5 they get lost someone knows how can I sum recursively the distance? thanks so much :D

```
distance(cdmx,michoacan,3).
distance(michoacan,jalisco,5).
distance(jalisco,durango,6).
distance(durango,nuevoleon,7).

connected(X,Y,Distance):-
   distance(X,Y,Distance).
connected(X,Y,Distance):-
   distance(X,Z,Distance1),
   connected(Z,Y,Distance2),
   Sum is Distance1+Distance2,
   write(Sum).`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close. In your second `connected` predicate you just needed to set the value of `Distance`.

```
connected(X,Y,Distance):-
    distance(X,Y,Distance).
connected(X,Y,Distance):-
    distance(X,Z,Distance1),
    connected(Z,Y,Distance2),
    Distance is Distance1 + Distance2.
```

Now the query `?- connected(cdmx,nuevoleon,Distance).` works fine and results in `Distance = 21`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it helped  me a lot I was frustrated because it didn't work but I was so close